# Is it possible to hide the menu bar in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sublimetext2

I suspect the answer is no, but I've got to ask anyway, is there any way to hide the menu bar in Sublime Text 2 running in Linux?

Comment: Which OS? In Windows YES, in Linux not yet.

Comment: Ah, yes, I meant Linux, but the hack below works.  Edited question for clarity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<s>Ah, finally found people talking about it: http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=12441&p=48966&hilit=hide+menu+bar#p48966</s>

The long and short of it is no, this seems to be the one thing that can't be customized in Sublime 2.  >:-|

Edit: Wow, talk about me being glad to be wrong!

http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2726&p=39487&hilit=hide+menu+bar#p39487 outlines a <s>glorious</s> terrible hack that gets the job done beautifully!  To reproduce the steps here for redundancy:

The idea is to trick GTK into rendering the window as if you're using it in Unity (or the like) so it doesn't draw the menu bar despite Sublime telling it to.  It doesn't allow you to turn the menus back on without restarting, but for my purposes that's fine (it's all just a ctrl+shift+p away anyway) and it looks sooo much better without that bar.  Anyway here's how to do it in ubuntu and mint:

```
sudo apt-get install git-core valac-0.14 libvala-0.14-dev libgtk-3-dev gobject-introspection libgirepository1.0-dev libgtk2.0-dev autotools-dev automake autoconf intltool libtool
git clone git://github.com/gnome-globalmenu/gnome-globalmenu.git
cd gnome-globalmenu
git checkout gnome-3
autoreconf --force --install --verbose
./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make GTK2_MODULES_DIR=/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/modules GTK3_MODULES_DIR=/usr/lib/gtk-3.0/modules GLIB_COMPILE_SCHEMAS=/bin/true install
sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas
```

then invoke it with

```
GTK_MODULES=globalmenu-gtk /path/to/sublime_text
```

or better yet wrap a script around it.

Comment: Is there any reason why the developer just doesn't add an option to hide the menubar? I find it surprising that this amazing program lacks such a simple feature.

Comment: @Vreality on my Windows machine there is an option to toggle the menu. Why that doesn't exist in Linux? No idea...

Comment: @Urda I suspect that it has to do with integration into the menubar, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Vreality I'm not sure either, just noting that on certain platforms it IS possible. Why it's not an option for linux, I'm not sure :\

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu with Unity, the menu bar is merged into the top bar of the screen

[image: screenshot of Sublime Text on Ubuntu 12.04]

Answer (score 0):

I know this is for sublime text 2 but just in case someone needs it for sublime text 3.
To hide menu bar of Sublime Text 3 in linux go on

**View -> Hide Menu**

If you are having trouble in getting back your menu bar you can open your sublime command palette with **Ctrl+shift+p** then type **vmenu** and toggle back.